# Dont create new user with ParseFacebookUtils and Xamarin

Tags: c#, facebook, parse-platform, xamarin

I am looking through the [documentation](http://parse.com/docs/dotnet/api/Index.html) for the `ParseFacebookUtils` class and I see that there is a method that can be used to login the user in with their Facebook ID and token. This is great and exactly what I want.

However, when I looked further into the documentation, I saw this

> If a user for the given Facebook credentials does not already exist, a new user will be created.

This is a deal breaker for me. Is there no way to disable this and simply show that the user was not authenticated? I do not want to create a new user if this happens, I just want to show that the login was unsuccessful.

Answer (score 0):

You should associate the user with his facebook details if you want him to login with his facebook account, according to the [guide](https://parse.com/docs/dotnet/guide#users-linking):

```
if (!ParseFacebookUtils.IsLinked(user))
{
// Make your browser control visible
try
{
    await ParseFacebookUtils.LinkAsync(user, browser, null);
    // The user logged in with Facebook!
}
catch
{
    // User cancelled the Facebook login or did not fully authorize.
}
// Hide your browser control
}
```

If you dont want to do that and you just want to check if the current facebook account exists, there is a written method for this, you have to create your own.